# Incorrect Method of Making Same Hashcode for Anagrams

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, hashtable

I'm given a dictionary and I want to store anagrams in the same bucket. I've tried solving my problem by looking at similar questions, but I'm completely beat. I'm using the sorted string as my key, but some words that aren't anagrams produce the same hash. For instance, 'art' and 'slickest' have the same hash. Here's my code and TABLE_SIZE is the size of my table :

```
public int myHash(String str) {
    int hash = 0;

    char[] letters = str.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(letters);

    String convertedString = new String(letters);

    System.out.print("The string is: " + convertedString + " ");

    hash = convertedString.hashCode() % TABLE_SIZE;

    if (hash < 0) {
        hash += TABLE_SIZE;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

Comment: If your `TABLE_SIZE` is small you'll have a collision between `TABLE_SIZE` words at best.

Comment: What is your problem? Collisions? Or anagramms not going to same bucket?

Comment: Collisions. The anagrams go to the same bucket

Comment: If you think about it, this is unavoidable in general if `int` has a finite number of values.  Collisions are normal and expected when implementing hashtables -- the best you can ever do (unless you know the complete set of possible keys in advance and can expend serious CPU time hunting for a collision-free hash function) is to try to minimise them.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you cant use java data set implementations ?

You will need to use a chained hashtable I think or some other collision handling structure, as a perfect hash will be impractical to devise.

See here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution